# Trying to figure out Xcode directory system

Tags: c++, xcode, build, include, box2d

I'm a bit stuck trying to get box2D to compile and I think it's because I don't quite understand how Xcode handles its build directories.

Box2D is folder containing a set of header and source files (in various subdirectories, etc). I've added the Box2D folder to a coco touch static library project in Xcode and when I try to compile I get errors about header files not being found such as `<Box2D/Common/b2BlockAllocator.h>`.

I found that if I simply include the header with `#include "b2BlockAllocator.h"` it compiles fine and Xcode actually finds the file.

So I'm a bit stuck here, I'm assuming I need to find a way to get all includes to begin searching from the root project directory and not from the source files location but I'm not sure how I can do that in Xcode...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out!

In the targets settings page look for 'header search paths' and add the root build directory of your project to it.

Answer (score 0):

`<Box2D/Common/b2BlockAllocator.h>` should be found in a directory called `Box2D/Common`. You said that Box2D contains a set of header and source files. Are some of these headers in a subdirectory of `Box2D` called `Common`, or are they all directly under `Box2D`? If it's the latter, then that's your problem.